# enabling and disabling billing from my application?

Tags: google-app-engine

I looked in the documentation, but I did not find anything.

Suppose you have a small app, which during some months fits in the free app quota, and some other months it does not.

Since billing is per month, is there a way to configure my application so that billing is by default disabled and automatically activated only during the months when I need to use more resources than those under the free quota?

The question may sound silly, but I'm trying to understand if I can optimize the budget for extremely small realities, such as local no-profit organizations. I'd prefer to invest 9$ in resources when needed and not in the monthly fee when there's no traffic.

Comment: If you have non-profit organizations you support I would contact Google's Billing department.  They have said I believe that they will work with non-profit organizations to come to some sort of agreement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Google's Billing API to enable and disable billing automatically:

https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/requests

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to programmatically or automatically enable and disable billing.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? You can always enable billing and the free app quota are still available to you free. They only charge you for any usage exceeding the free quota! Plus you can set a daily budget limit. You can just set it to $1 to start with.